# Theorem 14.2 from Davidson Stochastic Limit heory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

In Theorem 14.2 of his book *Stochastic Limit Theory* Davidson establishes the bound

$$E[\big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\big|]\leq 4M\alpha$$

where $\alpha,M\geq0$ are constants, and $|X|\leq M$. He then writes:

"Since $\big|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\big| \leq 2M$ it follows that, for $p\geq1$, $\|E[X|\mathcal F]-E[X]\|_p \leq 2M(2\alpha)^{1/p}$"

Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y:=\left\lvert\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]-\mathbb E\left[X \right]\right\rvert$. It is already shown that $\mathbb EY\leqslant 4M\alpha$. Moreover, we know that $0\leqslant Y\leqslant 2M$ hence
$$
\mathbb E\left[Y^p\right]=\mathbb E\left[Y\cdot Y^{p-1}\right]\leqslant 
\mathbb E[Y] (2M)^{p-1}\leqslant 4M\alpha(2M)^{p-1}
=2^{p+1}M^p\alpha.
$$
Then take the power $1/p$ to get the wanted inequality.

Comment: Do you mean $Y:=\left\lvert\mathbb E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]-\mathbb E[X]\right\rvert$?

Comment: Yes. Now I have edited.